# T-sql COLLATE and Varchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When u use Varchar(max), it is 8000 chars for a variable, and around 2^32 for a column, what is COLLATE and how it affects that?

Thanks

Comment: VARCHAR(MAX) is **always** up to 2GB of data... where did you read it was only 8000 chars for a variable??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collation deterines how SQL Server sorts and compares string data (which `varchar` variables and column values are).

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a column or a variable of `varchar(max)`, it can take up to 2 GB of data and 2^31-1 characters. If you declare the column or variable as `nvarchar`, it can still only take 2 GB of data and (2^31-1) / 2 characters since each character takes up twice as much space. When you declare a `varchar` column or variable without the use of the `COLLATE` clause, the collation of the database is used. The ``COLLATE clause does not affect the capacity of the column or variable.

Comment: Not quit accurate
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: What are you claiming is not accurate?. Both varchar and nvarchar have the same max space. (Ignoring the extra 2 bytes). Since nvarchar takes up twice as much space, you get half as many characters (but the same total max space).

Comment: @Tony - Regardless of the collation, you still only get 2 GB of storage. How many characters that translates to can change on the collation but *in general* each character in a varchar takes up a byte per character and two bytes per character in a nvarchar.